# D3.js Visualizations from Local Files

Tags: d3.js

I have a mostly working code that can load one record, but I'm not sure how to expand it. The closest that I've been able to get is to pull 1 record  column names from a csv based on the logic from this bl.ocks code snippet.

How can I modify the function below to pull an entire dataset rather than just one record?

By modifying code from the bl.ocks code, below is what I've been able to achieve. But I'm still having trouble looping the second function into pulling every row. In R, I could do something like rowtoHTML(0:length(data))

```
      var rowToHtml = function( row ) {
         var result = "";
     for (key in row) {
       result += key + ": " + row[key] + "<br/>"
     }
     return result;
   }

   var previewCsvUrl = function( csvUrl ) {
     d3.csv( csvUrl, function( rows ) {
       d3.select("div#preview").html(
         "<b>First row:</b><br/>" + rowToHtml( rows[0] ));
     })
   }

  d3.select("body")
   .append("div")
     .attr("id", "preview")
     .style("margin", "5px")

previewCsvUrl("Test.csv")
```

This question has been asked before. I've tried to do my due diligence by reading through similar questions, but was not able to use the recommended solution based off of my technology constraints or due to inexperience with Javascript. The sample code I've used comes from a trimmed version of this bl.ocks code: http://bl.ocks.org/hlvoorhees/9d58e173825aed1e0218

Edit - I understand that hosting a file locally is the right move, but its not an option for me (hence this approach). Python has been recommended for local hosting, but I'm unable to install it on my machine at this time. I'm working with Edge and IE as my two browser options. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: So, just as a recap, your boss/client wants you to: 1. give support to IE and Edge and; 2. load a local file **without** using a server. Is that correct? I wish you good luck, you'll need it!

Comment: he still needs to read the sandbox constraints of the browser. I don't see the reason to use Python in this. What kind of exotic machine do you use that you are unable to install Python. but that runs IE and Edge. Why not use the other popular browsers that have less problems implementing the W3 standards?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I know it's a bit wacky, but this issue arose because I am making a proof of concept metrics dashboard inside of a tightly controlled network. Python is possible to get, but not within the time constraint. I mostly included this information to show that I've explored that avenue.

Comment: You can copy data from file in a HTML element and read from there - then you don‘t need a web server.